# How to get JSON key and value with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json like this :

```
[{"name":"dhamar","address":"malang"}]
```

How can I get the key and value from that json with ajax?

I have tried code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '--url--',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(jsonData) {
        $.each(response,function(index,value)
        {
            $("[name="+index+"]").val(value);
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

but I get nothing. Anyone please help me, thanks

Comment: Why do you have `dataType: 'text'` if you need to work with JSON response?

Comment: $.parseJSON() did you use this ? What you get if you console log the json data ?

Comment: ups sorry, it should be 'json'

Comment: dataType:'text/json' , data:'jsonp'. do this after all

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Eh? What is that? Please read the documentation for `dataType` and `data` options before suggesting the nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `.success()` part:

```
.success: function(jsonData) {
    var response = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    console.log(response);
}
```

And remove `dataType: 'text',`.

You should see the object in your browser console and should be able to iterate with `.each()` from then on. Please share your results.

Comment: If the server returns the data with header `Content-Type: application/json`, jQuery will automatically parse the result and return JS object as `jsonData`.

Comment: i dont know what you mean, sir. I share what?

Comment: Change your code accordingly, open your console, and tell us what you see there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
$.each(response,function(key,value){

    console.log(key":"+value.name);
    console.log(key+":"+value.address);

})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8uk8N/)